# StackOverFlow website works on which technology

Tags: support, stack-overflow, technology

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which tools and technologies were used to build the Trilogy?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-were-used-to-build-the-trilogy)

StackOverFlow website works on which technology????

Comment: shouldn't it be moved to meta.stackoverflow?

Comment: Dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/what-was-stack-overflow-built-with

Comment: Mostly magic smoke, computrons, and CP/M.

Comment: Good grief. Do we have to move *every* one of these to meta, or can we just start closing them as "off topic" already?

Comment: Dude!!! Type this topic in the ask a question title, it won't show any similar post. I m a new user on StackOverFlow, but the way u all have treated this post, really was horrible.

Comment: @Adi: I put this question title into a new question on SO, and a question titled "Which technologies are used to built stackoverflow.com ?" came up 4th in the list. Next time, please consult the suggestion list more closely before posting. Thanks.